# Как сделать поддомен?

Tags: php

Сейчас страница доступна по адресу `url.ru/page/` 
Как сделать поддомен `page.url.ru/` ?

То есть, что бы по поддомену была доступна страница `url.ru/page/`

P.S.: да, можно создать `page.url.ru/`, туда поместить `index.html` с iframe страницы `url.ru/page/`, но это не то, что мне нужно...

Answer (score 1):

```
nano /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf        
$HTTP["host"] =~ "page.url.ru$" {        
server.document-root = "/srv/www/docs/page/"     
}
```

[Документация](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:Configuration).

А почему в тэгах php?

Answer (score 0):

с помощью **mod_rewrite** (htacces)

Comment: .htaccess не будем вводить в заблуждение пока еще не знающих